# Do I need to unsubscribe from an event in a c# metro application?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have subscribed various event in `OnNavigatedTo` like

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Loaded += Screen_Loaded;
}
```

I haven't unsubscribed this event. Does it cause any memory issue when this page is not needed??

Comment: It's Good Practice to unsubscribe event handlers when they are finished with

Comment: @MitchWheat Where should I unsubscribe them? From `OnNavigatedFrom` ??

Comment: @LewisBenge when will be the destructorcalled ? if I subscribe it's method to an event/delegate of some other object. In that case will it be garbage collected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. In this case you do not need to unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks. The reason is that you subscribe to an event on `this`. The garbage collector must identify this and free the object.

**But**, I would for other reasons still unsubscribe. For example having balanced resources makes the code easier to read. Also what if the OnNavigatedTo gets called twice? (Don't actually know if this can even happen) Then you'll have two subscriptions to the same method. Some would argue that unsubscribing in this scenario is redundant code and remove it. Although correct as such I would oppose such arguments.

You can try this short snippet to try it out yourself. Note: Never user finalizers or `GC.Collect()` except for learning about the GC like in this example.

```
public class Program
{
    private class Foo
    {
        public event EventHandler FooChanged;

        ~Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo was collected");
        }

        public void Bar()
        {
            FooChanged += UpdateUI;
        }

        private void UpdateUI(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.Bar();
        foo = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine("End of program");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you do have to unsubscribe from some event which might be automatically fired in a metro app

For Example :

Events such as

```
Window.Current.SizeChanged += Current_SizeChanged;

void Current_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //your code block contining various objects and logic
}
```

These events are not controlled by you as they are fire in the background. Any event which might not be related to a particular page (suppose the above event is initilized in the OnNavigatedTo Event) then you have to unsubscribe from it in events like OnNavigatedFrom

For further clarification initialize this event

```
Window.Current.SizeChanged += Current_SizeChanged;
```

and just keep a break point and change the size of the window change from landscape to snapped mode and this event will fire unless you have not unsubscribed from the event.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that:

1. You could accidentally subscribe to event several times (use -= to avoid this).
2. If event handler is a method from some other object, then that object will not be garbage collected until method is subscribed to an event.

Comment: +1 @Anton Do you have any links or references of your second b'cause I''m looking for the same :)